# Extract characters between semicolons in r

Tags: r, string, split

Trying to extract data between semicolons and put that data into new columns.

Here is some data

```
df <- data.frame(data = c("a;;c;d", "a;b;;d","a;;;d","a;b;;;"), num =c(1:4))
```

Here is what I have scraped together so far from S.O.

```
res <- df %>% 
  mutate(
    colA = str_extract(data, "^[^;]*(?=;)"),
    colB = str_extract(data, "(?<=;)[^;]*(?=;)"),
    colC = str_extract(data, "(?<=;)(?<=;)[^;]*(?=;)"),
    colD = str_extract(data, "(?<=;)[^;]*$")
  )
```

It nearly does what I want but `colC` is  the same as `colB`.  I dont really understand regex so a solution and a explanation would be gratefully received.

Comment: Why not `strsplit(df$data, ";")`?

Comment: This gives me a list, without the remaining data in the df.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### base R

```r
cbind(df, read.csv2(text = df$data, header = FALSE))
#     data num V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1 a;;c;d   1  a     c  d NA
# 2 a;b;;d   2  a  b     d NA
# 3  a;;;d   3  a        d NA
# 4 a;b;;;   4  a  b       NA
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(read.csv2(text = data, header = FALSE))
#     data num V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
# 1 a;;c;d   1  a     c  d NA
# 2 a;b;;d   2  a  b     d NA
# 3  a;;;d   3  a        d NA
# 4 a;b;;;   4  a  b       NA
```

This works *without explicit assignment* because `mutate` (and `summarize`) will happily take a named-`list` (of which `data.frame` is a special -- and compatible -- case).

Comment: Thank you, base R works a treat. Could not get the dplyr option to work it returned the starting df.

Comment: I don't know why it wouldn't be working given the sample data, perhaps it's a version thing? For this, I'm using R-4.0.5 (win10) and dplyr-1.0.5.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally to r2evans base R and dplyr:

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(data = c("a;;c;d", "a;b;;d","a;;;d","a;b;;;"), num =c(1:4))

df[, c("ColA", "ColB", "ColC", "ColD"):=tstrsplit(data, ";")]

df

     data num ColA ColB ColC ColD
1: a;;c;d   1    a         c    d
2: a;b;;d   2    a    b         d
3:  a;;;d   3    a              d
4: a;b;;;   4    a    b
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, using `tidyr::separate`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(data = c("a;;c;d", "a;b;;d","a;;;d","a;b;;;"), num =c(1:4))

df %>% 
  separate(data, into = str_c("col", letters[1:4]), sep=";", extra="drop")

#>   cola colb colc cold num
#> 1    a         c    d   1
#> 2    a    b         d   2
#> 3    a              d   3
#> 4    a    b             4
```